# Ionic 4 Image Display Bug

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I am developing a project in Ionic 4 (Angular). I have a page where I need to display some images.
The following code is used for image display:

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-12 *ngFor="let photo of photos">
    <div style="position:relative;">
      <button class="close" (click)="deletePhotoConfirmAlert(photo)" 
      style="right:0px; position: absolute; width:30px; height: 30px; 
        background-color: red; color: white">
        <span>&times;</span>
      </button>
      <img [src]="getImageSource(photo.attachmentId)">
    </div>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Where the button as the purpose of deleting an image, and the img tag is the image itself.
The [src] binding calls the function getImageSource, which actually makes an API call to the server and returns an image as a file:

```
 getImageSource(attachmentId) {
    return environment.apiUrl + 'attachments/download/?id=' + attachmentId;
  }
```

This is how it looks like:

Web version:

[image: Web version]

Mobile version (iOS):
[image: Mobile version]

As you can see, the image is not being displayed on mobile, it is just a small white square.
I have also tried on an android device and the same thing happens.
I should also mention that if uploading a photo from the mobile device (taking a camera photo), the picture is again shown as the small white square on the device, but if opened on the browser it is displayed correctly.

Note: The image is only for testing purposes, therefore out of context.

Comment: Any error on console?

Comment: @Piyush None, other than the native module not being able to access the camera on the browser, but that is not a problem because it opens the file select modal. On the mobile device it of course opens up the camera and has all the native functionalities.

Comment: Did you check if image is being loaded but present in small box or not?

Answer (score 1):

Set image height and width and try again.

```
 <img [src]="getImageSource(photo.attachmentId)" height="200" width="200">
```

**Or**

Check image url in browser.